# How to authenticate sharepoint 2013 by FedAuthCookie in .netcore3.1.0

Tags: csom

I am developing web application in **.net core 3.1.0**, for that i have to get documents stored in sharepoint 2013 using CSOM, the sharepoint app authenticates by FedAuthCookie.
In this [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard), it is explained that we have to use token authenticate sharepoint for .net standard apps. Is my understanding correct?

Is there any other way to connect sharepoint 2013(on-premises, which implements cookie based authentication) with .net core 3.1.0 or greater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSOM .NET Core does not support SharePoint on-prem. You'll need to use traditional .NET Framework CSOM.

Comment: Thanks Trevor Seward.